# Leaving out one of the Peano Axioms

Tags: examples-counterexamples, peano-axioms

What happens if you leave N4 (from [Ross' book](http://books.google.com/books?id=7b8_AAAAQBAJ&pg=PA2)) out of the Peano axioms which states that if $n$ and $m$ in $\mathbb{N}$ have the same successor, then $n = m$?

Comment: Some discussion of this, together with pictures illustrating Peano-like systems after omitting one axiom, is in H. Enderton: Elements of Set Theory, [page 70](http://books.google.com/books?id=JlR-Ehk35XkC&pg=PA70).

Comment: Can you state what the remaining (extralogical) axioms are, expecially are there still axioms left that contain an = ?

Answer (score 26):

This is the axiom that forces $\mathbb{N}$ to be infinite; if you drop it then you lose the requirement that your 'set of natural numbers' be infinite.

$\mathbb{N}$ would satisfy the remaining axioms, but so would the set $\{ 0, 1 \}$, where we define $\mathtt{succ}(0)=1$ and $\mathtt{succ}(1)=1$. In fact any set of the form $\{ 0, 1, \cdots, n \}$ (for $n \ge 1$) would satisfy the remaining Peano axioms if we define $\mathtt{succ}(k)=k+1$ for $k < n$ and $\mathtt{succ}(n)=n$.

Comment: I believe that we have to assume that the successor of each element of $n$ is $n + 1$, so I don't think we can define the successor of $n$ to be itself.

Comment: @SidRohan: Why do you say that? You just dropped precisely the axiom that tells you that has to be the case.

Comment: But one of the other axioms is "If $n$ belongs to $\mathbb{N}$, then its successor $n + 1$ belongs to $\mathbb{N}$". Doesn't that require the successor of $n$ to be $n + 1$?

Comment: Right, so we're defining what '+1' means. I wrote '$\mathtt{succ}$' to disambiguate: where I write $+1$ I mean the standard successor operation on the natural numbers, and where I write $\mathtt{succ}$ I mean the new successor operation on our new set which satisfies the remaining axioms. If I were to use this '+1' notation then what I'm saying is that we actually define $n+1$ to be equal to $n$... and the set we obtain would satisfy all the Peano axioms except the one you're omitting.

Comment: @Sid: No, it is "If $n$ is an element of the universe then the successor of $n$ is an element of the universe". There's nothing there that requires that "successor" means "the number plus one, computed with the addition we already know". If we already know how addition works, then what would we need axioms for?

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Thanks, that's a much clearer way of saying what I was trying to say.

Comment: I really don't get why this axiom 'is **the** axiom that forces $\mathbb N$ to be infinite'. Why is it any more worthy than the others?

Comment: Couldn't we define succ(1) = 0? That would make the set finite and would satisfy the axioms, no?

Comment: @TobiasBrandt: That would violate the axiom that 0 is not the successor of any number.

Comment: @Git Gud - you start with $0$; you have the function *Successor(x)* that, when applied to $0$ get $S(0)$. You have the axiom that tells you that $0$ is **not** the successor of any number. But, without "our" axioms, you cannot exclude a finite "cycle" obtained putting $S(n)=1$ for $n \ge 1$. This is avoided by the axiom, in *contrapositive* form, that says, if $n$ and $m$ are *distinct*, their successors must be *distinct*. In the previous "cycle" we have that $n \ne 0$ and $0$ are *distinct* but have the same successor (i.e. $1$).

Comment: @yatima2975: Ah, forgot about that.

Comment: @GitGud: Perhaps it was a bold statement to make. But the fact $\mathbb{N}$ is infinite is encoded by saying 'there is an injection from $\mathbb{N}$ to itself which is not a bijection', which only requires two of the axioms (this being one of them).

Answer (score 9):

If you omit the axiom $\, Sm = Sn\,\Rightarrow\, m=n\,$ then $S$ need no longer be $1$-$1,\,$ so the axioms now admit finite "dipper" semigroup models, where the orbit of $S$ starting from $0$ need not be an infinite half-line, but may be shaped like the big dipper (i.e. shaped like the letter $\rho),\,$ with an initial preperiod followed by a periodic part. If $\, S^{j+k}0 = S^j0\,$ with $\,j,k\,$ minimal then $\,0,S0,\ldots,S^{j-1}0\, $ is the preperiod, and a periodic cycle of length $\,k\,$ starts at $\,S^j0 = S^{j+k}0 = S^{j+2k}0 =\, \ldots \,$

Answer (score 0):

If you omit the axiom  $ Sm = Sn \to m =n $ then you loose a equalness there is just N3 left $ \forall x \lnot ( 1 =  Sx) $ butthat doesn't really say anything about equalness , how are you going to proof that 1 = 1?

Answer (score 0):

Leaving out only N4 of your Peano axioms, you would admit the possibility of a finite structure with $N=\{1,2,3, ... n\},$ $n>1$ and $S(k)=k+1$ for all $k< n$, and $S(n)=m$ for some $m,$ $1<m\leq n,$ i.e. a finite loop not including $1$ through $m-1.$

Leaving out only N3 ($S(x)\neq 1$) would admit the possibility of a finite structure with $N=\{1,2,3, ... n\},$ and $S(k)=k+1$ for all $k< n$, and $S(n)=1,$ i.e. a finite loop including all of $N.$ It would also admit the possibility of a chain going off to infinity in both directions (like the integers).

Leaving out only N5 (induction) would admit the possibility of any number of disjoint finite side loops or chains going off to infinity in both directions (like the integers), each of which would be not be connected to the set we want. See for [example](http://www.upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Domino_effect_visualizing_exclusion_of_junk_term_by_induction_axiom.jpg) where the dominoes represent elements of $N$. N5 filters out all such "junk terms".

See "What is a number again?" at my [math blog](http://www.dcproof.wordpress.com/).

BTW, your reference makes use of the + operator in N2 and N5. It hasn't been defined. Instead of $n+1,$ the author should have written "the *unique* successor of n."